Regarding creating an auto clicker app in Java Android Studio
I am new in Android Development in Java and currently want to create an auto clicker that will find the image placed at my res/drawable/settings_button.png after clicking another button named Start. I have basically created a class like this:
public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {
    private Bitmap targetImage;
    public void performAction() {
        performClickAction(0,0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        Log.d("error","This Function is triggered");
        if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED ||
                event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED) {
            AccessibilityNodeInfo rootNode = getRootInActiveWindow();
            if (rootNode == null) return;

            loadTargetImage();

            if (targetImage == null) return;

            Rect imageBounds = findImageBounds(rootNode, targetImage);
            if (imageBounds != null) {
                int clickX = imageBounds.left + (imageBounds.width() / 2);
                int clickY = imageBounds.top + (imageBounds.height() / 2);

                performClickAction(clickX, clickY);
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(this, "Image not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }

    private void loadTargetImage() {
        targetImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.settings_button);
    }

    private Rect findImageBounds(AccessibilityNodeInfo rootNode, Bitmap targetImage) { if (rootNode == null || targetImage == null) return null;

        Bitmap screenBitmap = getBitmapFromNode(rootNode);
        if (screenBitmap == null)
            return null;

        Rect matchBounds = templateMatching(screenBitmap, targetImage);
        screenBitmap.recycle();
        return matchBounds;
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmapFromNode(AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo) {
        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        nodeInfo.getBoundsInScreen(bounds);

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bounds.width(), bounds.height(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            /*
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            nodeInfo.draw(canvas);
            */
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Out of memory", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
    private Rect templateMatching(Bitmap screenBitmap, Bitmap targetImage) {
        int screenWidth = screenBitmap.getWidth();
        int screenHeight = screenBitmap.getHeight();
        int targetWidth = targetImage.getWidth();
        int targetHeight = targetImage.getHeight();

        for (int y = 0; y <= screenHeight - targetHeight; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x <= screenWidth - targetWidth; x++) {
                boolean match = true;
                for (int ty = 0; ty < targetHeight; ty++) {
                    for (int tx = 0; tx < targetWidth; tx++) {
                        if (screenBitmap.getPixel(x + tx, y + ty) != targetImage.getPixel(tx, ty)) {
                            match = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!match) break;
                }
                if (match) {
                    return new Rect(x, y, x + targetWidth, y + targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void performClickAction(int x, int y) {
        Log.d("error","This Function is triggered");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Mouse click performed at (" + x + ", " + y + ")", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        SystemClock.sleep(1000);
        int metaState = 0;
        long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100;
        MotionEvent motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(
                downTime,
                eventTime,
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,
                x,
                y,
                metaState
        );

        view.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);

    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {
        // Handle interrupt event
    }
}

There are basically three problems that I am facing:

How do I call the onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) function from my start button click listener? I mean I just cannot do that since I do not know what to pass as the parameter. Moreover, I created another function named performAction() to generate programmatic mouse clicks at coordinate (0,0) so that the function onAccessibilityEvent() gets triggered.
It says view.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent); is incorrect. I have imported import android.view.View; and still facing this error. But why?
Is this part of the code:

/*
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            nodeInfo.draw(canvas);
*/

necessary to be present. I mean why do I need a canvas. Is not it enough to just get the bitmap version of my targeted UI to fit the Rect() there?
Any detailed documentation and help would be largely appreciated. Thanks.

I know View is not allowed to be used with Services(). Any other choices of how may I set an auto clicker on images? I may need to work with Robot too?
